# Using CMakes CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG with nvcc/cuda

Tags: cuda, cmake, nvcc, compiler-flags

I'm trying to compile some coda using CUDA with MakeFiles generated by CMake.

I'd like to use CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG or something similar to check if the used nvcc version supports a given flag. In my case it is "--expt-relaxed-constexpr" (Cuda 7.5) and "--relaxed-constexpr" (Cuda 7?)

Of course I could compare the CUDA version but I find the compile-flag check more fail-safe.

Is there any CMake command similar to CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG that invokes the nvcc compiler and not the host compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of an official way to check for a specific `nvcc` flag, but you can write a macro yourself rather simply:

**CheckNvccCompilerFlag.cmake**

```
MACRO(CHECK_NVCC_COMPILER_FLAG _FLAG _RESULT)
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND ${CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE} "${_FLAG}" ERROR_VARIABLE NVCC_OUT)
    IF("${NVCC_OUT}" MATCHES "Unknown option")
        SET(${_RESULT} 0)
    ELSE()
        SET(${_RESULT} 1)
    ENDIF()
ENDMACRO()
```

---

**A demo use:**

**CMakeList.txt**

```
PROJECT(cuda_flag_test)
FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA)
INCLUDE(CheckNvccCompilerFlag.cmake)
CHECK_NVCC_COMPILER_FLAG("--asdf" HAS_NVCC_ASDF)
IF(HAS_NVCC_ASDF)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "asdf is supported")
ENDIF()

CHECK_NVCC_COMPILER_FLAG("--relaxed-constexpr" HAS_NVCC_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR)
IF(HAS_NVCC_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "relaxed-constexpr is supported")
ENDIF()
```

**output**

```
...

-- Found CUDA: /opt/cuda (found version "7.0") 
-- relaxed-constexpr is supported

...
```

---

(Personally, I would rely on [`CUDA_VERSION`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake).)

Comment: I guess this will work if one is careful with the options... Well a "there is none" is as well an answer.

Comment: @Flamefire why would you have to be more careful as when using `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG`?

Comment: The `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG` actually tries to compile something. Invokin nvcc like that makes it put out an error (no input files) and I'm not sure if `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG` handles the parameter specially. Here you can pass easily wrong stuff as a "flag" but I think then it's the users fault so this is ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, there is. NVCC will define a macro: `__CUDACC_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR__`.

```
#ifdef __CUDACC_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR__

  do somthing

#endif
```